# Better understanding of the relationship between the user and memcached

Tags: php, codeigniter, memcached

OK I think I missed the point when learning about memcached or I just don't know what I am doing.

Basically I am integrating memcached (using CodeIgniter) into my app to save load time. I assumed that the key:value pairs that I stored would be unique to the current user. Apparently that is not the case because when another user logs in, they get the first users cached values, including the user profile.

If memcached key:value pairs are shared across all users then it seems that "nothing" unique to the current user can be cached, or am I completely missing something (I hope so).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: generally you don't cache user specific data, only the 'generic' stuff

Comment: This sounds like an incredibly naive question but what is 'generic'? If the app is getting data from a database then it will 'always' will have some uniqueness to it.

Comment: most apps\sites are generic the same data is served to every one, that's by point. if it has to be new every time due to user specs, then there would be no poin in caching

Comment: Maybe this is another lesson to be learned,... Are you referring to caching stuff that is not coming from a database? If not, then why hold generic info in a database in the first place. That seems like inefficient way to get and serve data to the browser. I really appreciate your feedback!

Comment: every cms\e-shop etc i know stores everything in a db, its standard practice. There is very little data stored in 'flat' files anymore the flexibility a db offers far out-ways the minuscule time it takes to query and retrieve the data it holds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

memcached itself has no concept of what your application is, it is a simple key-value store.  As such, from the context of your application, the key-space is 'shared.'

If you want to be able to cache content for each user separately, simply create a unique key for said content for each user.  Since it is likely that you already have a unique identifier for each of your users, you can generate your key based off of that.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This was the angle that I was considering going down, however now I am hearing that "generally you don't cache user specific data" which seems odd to me. I'll keep reading into all the memcached resources that I can find.

Comment: I strongly disagree with that 'no user specific data' sentiment. Any time you have data that is costly to fetch/compute and are largely static, they are great candidates for integration with memcache. Most web content is rarely updated but read often so caching makes a lot of sense. It might even make sense to have a memcache layer between your app data model and your DB. Repeated reads will see a benefit. If your access pattern is reversed, i.e. write-heavy and rarely-read, then you'll not get a lot out of memcached.  Caching is 'easy,' knowing when to expire your cache is hard.

Comment: This is good advice. Much appreciated! I am going to proceed with caching the users profile and a few other user specific items to prevent querying for them on each and every page load. In my app the users profile is not very likely to be updated regularly at all. Now I just need to find the "best" ttl's.